# how to use Boolean with if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing logic if Payload has value "null" and " "(empty) it should not process value and if it finds some value (eg:"89") then it should process value using Boolean expression in if condition **if 'Null' in y or 'None' in y:**. It checks for attribute value null and empty but if it finds some value it should return some Boolean expression.

```
payload=[{'id': 'Room1','pressure': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': ''},'temperature'{'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': 'Null'},'humidity'{'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': '89','type': 'RoomTest'}]
attrs=['temperature','pressure','humidity']
x=(len(payload))
for i in range(x):
    for j in attrs:
       y=payload[i][j]['value']
       print(y)
       if 'Null' in y or 'None' in y:
          print('Notification Not processed because of Null or empty value')
       else:
          print('Notification successfully processed')
```

Null or some value such as "89". so, it will check in loop for "Null and None" value and in case if gets value "89" in third case it will exit from code and jump to else part of code "'Notification successfully processed'"
Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated!Thanks

Comment: Try `if not y:`

Comment: isn't "else" doing the same work in above code.

Comment: just to clarify can you add expected output?

Comment: I want if payload has multiple attribute values such as it has : " "(empty string) , Null or some value such as "89". so, it will check in loop for "Null and None" value and in case if gets value "89" in third case it will exit from code and jump to else part of code "'Notification successfully processed'".

Comment: And if gets no null value in payload it will jump to else part of code.

Comment: Add this info in your question not in comment and provide output based on the input that you provided

Comment: To check if y is equal to a list of different values, you could do `if any(y.lower() == s for s in ['null', 'none', ''])`

Answer (score 0):

Then try simple code, there is no need to write every case in python. Just use ***not***

```
if not y:
      print('Notification Not processed because of Null or empty value')
   else:
      print('Notification successfully processed')
```